# Cannot show images on tkinter(sockets proggraming)

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I'm working on a project of a share screen between 2 computers. now, I'm sure that the server code that send the screenshots works well(I see that it creats a screen shot every second).
Now, I have some bugs in the client program.
First, I get only the first screenshot from the server, and then it stops getting new images.
Second, I see a white window of tkinter, and after few seconds, it crashes.
I don't get any errors.
My question is How to fix it in the client program( and if it's necessary in the server so also there, although I don't think)

Client code:

```py
import socket
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pyautogui
from threading import Thread
import time

label = None

def client_program():
   client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 2000))
   thread = Thread(target=sharescreen(client_socket))
   thread.start()
   while True:
      print(1)

def receiving_image(client_socket):
   while True:
      file = open("screenshot.png", "wb")
      data = client_socket.recv(1024)
      while data:
         file.write(data)
         data = client_socket.recv(1024)
      file.close()

def resize_image(window_width, window_height):
   image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Proggramers Club\CLIENT - THE HACKER\screenshot.png")   
   resized_image = image.resize((window_width, window_height))
   photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
   
   return photo_image

def sharescreen(client_socket):
   root = tk.Tk()
   root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
   root.update()
   window_width = root.winfo_width()
   window_height = root.winfo_height()
   root.after(1000, change_background(client_socket))
   
   
   root.mainloop()

def change_background(client_socket):
   global label
   receiving_image(client_socket)
   screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
   photo_image = resize_image(screen_width, screen_height)
   label.config(image = photo_image)
   label.image = photo_image
   print(1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
   client_program()
```

Server code:

```
import socket
import threading
import pyautogui
import time


def victim_program():
    victim_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    victim_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1",2000))
    print("Listening")
    victim_socket.listen(1)
    client, _ = victim_socket.accept()
    print("Connected")
    while True:
        share_screen_victim(client)




def share_screen_victim(client):
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    
    screenshot.save(r"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Proggramers Club\Server - The victim\screenshot.png")    
    send_image(client)
    time.sleep(1)

def send_image(client):
    file = open("screenshot.png", "rb")
    data = file.read()
    client.sendall(data)
    file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    victim_program()
```

I checked if the change_background function is on loop by printing 1 every call and I didn't get anything, and it make me be confused. Just tell me what do you thing that I should do.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing anything because your code is stuck in infinite while loop:

```py
thread = Thread(target=sharescreen(client_socket))
```

In this line you aren't even getting to the thread creation because you called the `sharescreen` function which is never finished.

(You used parenthesis which call the function, if you want to pass it as an argument you should use: `Thread(target=sharescreen, args=(client_socket,))`)

The `sharescreeen` function calles the `change_background` function which calls the `receiving_image` function that has an infinite `while` loop in it, so your code never get to the part when it reads and changes the image on the screen.

As [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) mentioned,

> "there is no protocol implemented to know when one has received a complete image. The data recv loop will read until the client socket is closed, which is never"

You are seeing a white window because you create it before the infinite `while-loop`.

---

** Note:
You also forgot to define `label`.

Comment: In addition there is no protocol implemented to know when one has received a complete image.  The data recv loop will read until the client socket is closed, which is never.

Comment: Also the `root.after(1000, change_background(client_socket))`, should actually be `root.after(1000, change_background, client_socket)`. Otherwise `change_background` gets called immediately